# How big can a sphere of water in low earth orbit get?

Tags: surface-tension, tidal-effect

Imagine that you have a large space station in low earth orbit, and inside that space station is a large sphere of water. How big can that sphere of water get before tidal forces overwhelm surface tension and cohesion and tear it apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equate surface tension given centripetal acceleration $a_{\gamma}$ to [a tidal force given acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) outwards from a sphere $a_t$ :

$$ \frac {2 \pi r~\gamma}{m} = GM \frac {2r}{d^3}  \tag 1$$

Expressing water sphere mass as $m=\rho~ 4/3 \pi r^3$ and solving for $r$ gives :

$$ r = \left(\frac {3}{4} \frac{d^3 \gamma}{GM\rho}\right)^{1/3} \tag 2$$

Assuming [water surface tension](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/surface-tension-d_962.html) $\gamma \approx 0.0728~N/m$ and distance of low orbiting droplet $d = 8413~km$ from Earth center,- substituting data into (2) gives

water droplet radius $r \approx 4.34~\text{m}$. When it reaches this radius it should be teared apart by Earth gravitational force, because it is within [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit), which for water density objects is $\approx 2\times$ greater than low earth orbit radius.